# Trigger to Populate a Lookup field on Opportunity

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage, failing-tests

I have created a Trigger to auto populate a lookup field on Opportunity as that was not possible with a workflow and had to reference that field in Exact target as in Exact Target we can only refer Contact Fields.

The trigger is working fine:

```
trigger testConversion2 on Lead (after insert,after update) {
  List<Opportunity> opps = new List<Opportunity>();
  Map<Id,Id> association = new Map<Id,Id>();

  for(Lead l : Trigger.new) {
    if(l.IsConverted && (l.ConvertedOpportunityId != null) ) {
      association.put(l.ConvertedOpportunityId, l.ConvertedContactId);
    }
  }

  opps = [SELECT ContactLookup__c FROM Opportunity WHERE Id IN : association.keySet()];

  for (Opportunity o: opps) {
    o.ContactLookup__c = association.get(o.Id);
  }

  update opps;
}
```

However am struggling with the test class its giving me a DML Exception error.

```
@isTest
private Class testConversion2 {
  private static Id leadId;
  static {
    Lead testLead = new Lead();
    testLead.FirstName = 'Test First';
    testLead.LastName = 'Test Last';
    testLead.Company = 'Test Co';

    insert testLead;

    leadId = testLead.Id;
  }

  static testMethod void Test_LeadConvert(){
    test.StartTest();

    Database.LeadConvert lc = new database.LeadConvert();
    lc.setLeadId(leadId);
    LeadStatus convertStatus = [Select Id, MasterLabel from LeadStatus where IsConverted=true limit 1];
    lc.setConvertedStatus(convertStatus.MasterLabel);
    Database.LeadConvertResult lcr = Database.convertLead(lc);
    System.assert(lcr.isSuccess());

    test.StopTest();
  }
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is the error that you are receiving ?

Comment: System.DmlException: ConvertLead failed. First exception on row 0; first error: FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION, Validation error on Lead: Conversion allowed only for leads with status as "Qualified for contact": []

Comment: Looks like you need to set the value to the on specified, since you may have multiple "qulaified" statuses and the Validation Rule is seeking another.

Comment: Also, have you considered using Flows?    These can handle lookups and variable assignments to lookup fields.  They are pretty intuitive to build and requrie no code.

Comment: @james i am new to apex can you explain?

Comment: Check this out.    http://help.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_vpm_implementation_guide.pdf  These are basically more advanced Workflow Rules, which can run  "Flows".  In flows, you can do basic actions one would typically encounter in a trigger -- such as loop over collection, query, delete, insert, update records.   Here's some mre information.     https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=process_action_flow.htm&language=en_US